# Any simple EigenFaces classification code in R

Tags: r, pca

I am just a novice R coder, and have been inspired by the use of PCA and the eigenfaces techniques to classify images.  However most examples appear to be in Python, and I would prefer to continue development in R.

I have loaded Cambridge greyscale face images into a 400 sample x 10304 column ImageData,  with each column representing the folded out 112x92 greyscale pixel value. I can plot each image using pixmapRGB OK.

I perform PCA analysis, and believe I have extracted the Eigenvalues, but when I reconstitute my first image, from 50 EigenFaces, it still a long way off, more like a rough EigenFace.

So I don't think I am processing my Image means and scale properly correctly, or correctly (I have tried with and without colmeans average image, and prcomp without Center =FALSE.

So I am really looking for some end to end EigenFaces classificational code in R

```
cmeans = colMeans(TrainImages)
DisplayImage(cmeans, main = "Average Person")
ProcTrainData = TrainImages  # - cmeans

# Now PCA Analysis - Adjusted Tolerance to 0.125 to return ~50 PCs
PCAProcess = prcomp(ProcTrainData, center = TRUE, tol = 0.125)

# Analyse PCA results Results
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
screeplot(PCAProcess)
devs = PCAProcess$sdev ^ 2 / sum(PCAProcess$sdev ^ 2)
plot(1 - devs, main = "Percent Variance Explained", type = "l")

EigenFaces = PCAProcess$rotation

# Project Training Data into PCA Eignevalue space
TrainPCAValues = ProcTrainData %*% EigenFaces

# Plot first ten EigenFaces
par(mfrow = c(2, 5))
par(oma = rep(2, 4), mar = c(0, 0, 3, 0))

for (i in 1:10) {
    DisplayImage(EigenFaces[, i], main = paste0("EF ", i))   #PCs from sample data
}
# ======== Recover the first Image by the use of PCA attributes and Eigen
# Images
Composite[1:ImageSize] = 0    # PCAProcess$center; 
for (iv in 1:50) {
    Composite = Composite + TrainPCAValues[1, iv] * EigenFaces[, iv]
}

DisplayImage(Composite)
DisplayImage(TrainImages[1, ])
DisplayImage(PCAProcess$center)
```

Eigen Faces
[image: Eigen Faces]

Generated Composite vs Original 1st Sample
[image: Generated Composite vs Original 1st Sample]

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit of progress.
Basically I have decided to ignore calculating mean before the prcomp call, and instead use prcomp to calculate scale and centre:

```
enter code here# Adjusted Tolerance to 0.05 to return ~50 PCs
PCAProcess = prcomp(TrainImages,center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE   ,tol=0.05)
#
# Analyse PCA results Results
summary(PCAProcess)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
screeplot(PCAProcess)
devs = PCAProcess$sdev^2 / sum(PCAProcess$sdev^2)
plot(1-devs, main='Percent Variance Explained', type='l')
#
# The PCA Process will have reduced the Original Image Dimension 96x96 =    9216 down to ~50 
# The Rotated Data into ~50 dimension is in PCAProcess$x arrays   (
# The Eigen Rotatations of the original dimensionare captued in     PCAProcess$rotation 
#
# Looks like we can get away with use of 25 PCs  to get about 95% or varience 
EigenFaces = PCAProcess$rotation[,1:25];
# Plot first ten EigenFaces
par(mfrow=c(2, 5))
par(oma = rep(2, 4), mar=c(0, 0, 3, 0))
for (i in 1:10){
     im <- matrix(data=rev(EigenFaces[,i]), nrow=96, ncol=96)
 image(1:96, 1:96, im, col=gray((0:255)/255))
 }
#
# Training Reconstruction Matrix *just first 25 attributes in PCA space
ReconstructTraining = PCAProcess$x[,1:25]%*%t(EigenFaces)
#
# Need to unscale and uncentre back using the prcomp computed scale and centre
#
if(PCAProcess$scale != FALSE){
 ReconstructTraining <- scale(ReconstructTraining, center = FALSE ,scale=1/PCAProcess$scale)
}
if(all(PCAProcess$center != FALSE)){
    ReconstructTraining <- scale(ReconstructTraining, center = -1 * PCAProcess$center, scale=FALSE)
}
# ============================
#Recover the first Image by the use of PCA attributes and Eigen Images
#
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
# Original Image 2
im <- matrix(data=rev(im.train[2,]), nrow=96, ncol=96)
image(1:96, 1:96, im, col=gray((0:255)/255))

RestoredImage <- matrix(data=rev(ReconstructTraining[2,]), nrow=96, ncol=96)
image(1:96, 1:96, RestoredImage, col=gray((0:255)/255))
```

Still not particularly good compared to the various EigneFaces Tutorials and papers.  So with use of 25 EigenFaces [Original vs reconstructed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF5jC.png)

The Python sklearn  EigenFaces appears to be a lot better than using R. So I will move onto using Python for Machine learning, as it appears to be better supported community.

Comment: Is the exampled you linked to from the same dataset? Have you tried plotting the standard deviations?